# Legacy Firebase conditions not working with curl

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

This call:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: key=AAAAx4uYEXU:...e8EEq9aCv-pGWXIfyCp_lUp28mY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "data": {
          "score": "5x1",
          "time": "15:10"
        },
        "condition": "'dogs' in topics || 'cats' in topics",
        "content_available": true
      }' \
  "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

Causes this error:
Invalid "condition" field: only support 'topics' conditions

I copied the condition field straight from the documentation... how can I get this to work?